# Bootstrap Carousel not sliding automatically in Rails 3.2.13

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

It **was working fine** a few minutes ago but now it's not working.I'm using the **bootstrap-sass** gem Is it because bootstrap just upgraded to **Bootstrap 3**?

That's my code.

```
    <head>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>  

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 1200,
      pause: 'false'
    })
  });
</script>

<div class="container" id="carousel">

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Carousel items -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item"><%= image_tag '4.jpg' %><div class="carousel-caption"><p>Caption text here</p></div></div>
        <div class="item"><%= image_tag '5.jpg' %><div class="carousel-caption"><p>Caption text here</p></div></div>
        <div class="item"><%= image_tag '2.jpg' %><div class="carousel-caption"><p>Caption text here</p></div></div>
        <div class="item"><%= image_tag '6.jpg' %><div class="carousel-caption"><p>Caption text here</p></div></div>
      </div>
      <!-- Carousel nav -->
      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" >&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Where is the problem. I'm Using **Rails 3.2.13**. Provide a solution.
Sometimes it shows

> TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function
>   [Break On This Error]
>
> pause: 'false'

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: that mean there is no carousel function in js file try updating ur file with carousel function

Comment: @Hushme I checked it. There is a carousel function.

Comment: use that file path pasted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this bootstrap file

```
 <script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yup.Thanks that worked. Bet'n what's the difference bet'n the two files?

Comment: you better should download that file